# Exporting content from EPiServer CMS 6 R2 to EPiServer CMS 7.5

Tags: migration, episerver, episerver-7, episerver-6-r2

I have a scenario where I export a portion of my page tree from an EPiServer CMS 6 R2 website with linked vpp-content included (mostly images and documents).

But when I import these pages into EPiServer CMS 7.5, the new pages does not maintain the relation to the linked content (which does get imported into asset blob storage).

Also, content stored in the VPP "PageFiles" does not get imported at all using export/import (from what I can see).

I ended up solving this using scheduled jobs producing CSV-files keeping track of the pages, their content and their external URL's and also by manually uploading the pagefiles.

My questions is, is this even supposed to work? Or what is the recommended way of achieving successful export/import between 6R2 and 7.5 with preserved page <-> content relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you need to import to 7.0/7.1 and the run then migration tool to get a 6R2 export all the way to 7.5.

It's stated here that 6R2 to 7.0 works in most cases: http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/Thread.aspx?id=64767&epslanguage=en

For most export/import and mirroring scenarios (except between different environments of the same solution) I recommend building the transfer by hand.

Comment: Thanks! I have succesfully exported/imported content using the following setup: 1) Exported from EPi 6R2. 2) Imported into temporary empty EPi 7 site. 3) Upgraded EPi 7 to EPi 7.5 using deployment center. 4) Exporting from EPi 7.5 (temp) 5) importing to my destination web (7.5). No VPP-migration tool used whatsoever!